# Typecast child component properties to ini file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm currently having a major headache with typecasting of component properties.

On my form, i have a TPanel called "scene". Also on the form, i have a button that creates a `TSelection`, and within that `TSelection` creates a `TImage` and then load a picture into that TImage. The name for the TSelection is assigned via a TEdit known as "ImgObjName". It then writes this name to an inifile. The events for the TSelection are assigned to procedures elsewhere in the code. As you know, the TSelection component can be moved around (and resized) at runtime. The TImage has it's HitTest turned off while the TSelection has it turned on.

The above works as i want it to, but the next part is where i'm stuck. Essentially, on a timer, i want to write a select few of the properties of each child component to an TMemIniFile. There's 2 ways i'm willing to do this;
1) Write the properties of each child to seperate TMemInifiles.
2) Write the properties of each child to a single TMemIniFile, but make the `section` identify which component the values in that section relate to.

I've tried a few different methods, but all of them have caused me some major problems (usually "index out of bounds").

My current method is as such;

`ChgPos` is a global boolean variable which is TRUE when the the mousedown event on one of the TSelection objects is fire, and FALSE when the MouseUp event is fired. This boolean procedure works perfectly for these purposes so no changes are needed there.

`TimerBar` is a `TTrackBar` that's been created at designtime. It's value changes based on a timer.

`AnimIni` is the TMemIniFile which has been assigned earlier in the code. For this purpose, i've set it not to free up the file (so as there's no access violations).

```
var
  i: Integer;
  PosX, PosY: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Scene.ChildrenCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Scene.Components[i] is TSelection then
    begin
      PosX := AnimIni.ReadInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) + '_Object' +
        IntToStr(i), 'PosX', PosX);
      PosY := AnimIni.ReadInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) + '_Object' +
        IntToStr(i), 'PosY', PosY);
    end;
  end;
  if ChgPos = False then
  begin
    if Scene.Components[i] is TSelection then
    begin
      (Scene.Components[i] as TSelection).Position.X := PosX;
      (Scene.Components[i] as TSelection).Position.Y := PosY;
    end;
  end
  else if ChgPos = True then
  begin
    AnimIni.WriteInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) + '_Object' +
      IntToStr(i), 'PosX', Round((Scene.Children[i] as TSelection).Position.X));
    AnimIni.WriteInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) + '_Object' +
      IntToStr(i), 'PosY', Round((Scene.Children[i] as TSelection).Position.Y));
  end;
end;
```

I'm struggling to figure out where to go with this. I'm getting "Index out of range" errors with it. I'll also need to save the TImage component properties (particularly the parent and Bitmap location, but i feel it's important for me to get the code working with at least one component at the moment).

I'm somewhat new to typecasting (as all my previous projects worked without the need for it), but all my experience with it so far has been pleasently successful. It's just in this particular case it's proven to become more complicated than i can work out without some assistance.

I did try `WriteComponent` and `ReadComponent` and using multiple files to stream the data in realtime in relation to the value of TimerBar but it's much too slow for what i want to achieve (particularly on the write function). The inifile method does work from my earlier testing, but it's actually working with typecasting of multiple components that are created at runtime that i'm having issues with.

Can anyone shed some light on a potential solution or the direction i should head in?

Comment: Your i loop ends too soon. The state of i in your `if ChgPos` (and the rest) is undetermined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You are mixing components and children. If you loop through all children of the panel, do not use that index on the `Components` property, but the `Children` property. (I assume your code compiled and XE2 has a `Children` property, otherwise I think you mean `Controls` and `ControlCount`).
2. Like LU RD already commented, you are using the for-loop variable `i` outside the for-loop. I am sure you want it inside. You are also warned by the compiler for this:

   > FOR-loop variable 'i' may be undefined after loop

   Always make sure you have zero! compiler errors, warnings and hints.
3. I do not understand your routine logic for it loads the settings even if you actually want to write them. I think you only want to load the settings from the MemIniFile when `ChgPos` is false.

No guarantees given, but I think the routine should look like this (including a few syntax improvements):

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Selection: TSelection;
  PosX, PosY: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Scene.ChildrenCount - 1 do
    if Scene.Children[i] is TSelection then
    begin
      Selection := Scene.Children[i] as TSelection;
      if ChgPos then
      begin
        AnimIni.WriteInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) + '_Object' +
          IntToStr(i), 'PosX', Round(Selection.Position.X));
        AnimIni.WriteInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) + '_Object' +
          IntToStr(i), 'PosY', Round(Selection.Position.Y));
      end
      else
      begin
        PosX := AnimIni.ReadInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) +
          '_Object' + IntToStr(i), 'PosX', PosX);
        PosY := AnimIni.ReadInteger(IntToStr(Round(TimerBar.Value)) +
          '_Object' + IntToStr(i), 'PosY', PosY);
        Selection.Position.X := PosX;
        Selection.Position.Y := PosY;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Although I seriously doubt the default values for the `AnimIni.ReadInteger` function, `PosX` and `PosY`, which are unassigned. If no section in the ini file is found, then `PosX` and `PosY` will have arbitrary values. You should initialize them to whatever makes sense.

Comment: I guess the Children property must be FMX.

Comment: That's exactly what it was NGLN. "Children" is indeed the FMX property.

As it was, there was no warning or hint about the loop (and only about variables which i hadn't used from other procedures)

Because of the well-written explanation and code correction, i have to give this vote to your response, but since several people were of assistance, i've voted each of their answers up.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop counter and indexed properties don't match. `ComponentCount` and `Components[]` go together. And `ChildrenCount` and `Children[]` go together. You want to work with the latter pair since you are interesting in the children of the controls. The `ComponentCount` and `Components[]` properties refer to ownership which is a different concept.

What's more your loop ends but you continue using the loop variable after the loop variable. That's clearly wrong. It looks like it needs to be inside the loop and inside the `Scene.Children[i] is TSelection` test.

<sub>As an aside `ChildrenCount` is grammatically incorrect alongside `ComponentCount` and `ControlCount`. This property should have been named `ChildCount`.</sub>